# DbContext ChangeTracker: Id of Added Entity for Auditing

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I have something like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var changeLog in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added ||
               p.State == EntityState.Deleted ||
               p.State == EntityState.Modified)
        .SelectMany(entity => AuditRecords(entity)))
    {
        this.ChangeLogs.Add(changeLog);
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

But, of course, audited change logs will not contain the primary key value of the entity when the EntityState is Added (until after SaveChanges). How can I obtain the primary key value for change auditing purposes?

Richard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd store the references to the entities in a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (or an array, or other such structure) and *then* make the call to the underlying implementation of `SaveChanges`.

When the call is complete, because your entities are reference types (best practices indicate they should be as they are mutable), the primary keys on those items in the list should be populated, at which point you can pass the list of changed entities to your audit layer.

Also, it appears that you are trying to add an entity that one Entity type and add it to another Entity type collection (whatever is exposed by `ChangeLogs`); I'd recommend against this.  If you are entering items in another entity set, do *not* reuse those entities, but copy the instances to the proper entity type.

Comment: I tried something like that (get a list of entries) but ran into issues accessing them again as they became detached after saving.

Comment: Only Deleted entities will be detached after saving. If you just keep track of the Added entities, which are the ones for which you need the keys, you should be fine.

Comment: @Richard I wouldn't recommend using the same entity instances for auditing (as it has it's own entity types) as the ones that were just updated.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Use GUIDs for primary key so your id's can be generated without hitting the database.