# How to detect if an Entity added to DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, entity-framework-5, savechanges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DBContext Added/Attached Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407860/dbcontext-added-attached-event)

I'm using a custom **`ID-Generating`** strategy in **EF 5**. I override the **`SaveChanges`** method to detect added entities and set them `ID`s. But the new entities's `ID` is not accessible until calling **`SaveChanges`**. I search SO and find some answers. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694696/dbcontext-changetracker-id-of-added-entity-for-auditing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407860/dbcontext-added-attached-event). In the second link, [`@KVerwold`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409014/974276) shows a way to detect changes that seems works. But it has just one up-vote and not accepted. Can I use @KVerwold's suggested way? Do you think it may couse any error -logical or any? **OR** do you have any other suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there is just one up vote because not too many people are implementing custom id generation.  Not sure what your requirements are, but it rarely passes the smell test in my opinion.

Comment: @jrummell If you see question clearly, you'll see I point your link myself. But thanks to pay attention

Comment: @Maess Thanks. If you post your test as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: That's how I found it :) Your question should really be a comment on that linked question.

Comment: Why do you think that votes show which solution is correct for you? Did the answer helped you? If yes, use it. Btw. if it has one vote and it helped you, you should also add your own vote. The answer is correct. I didn't know about that option when writing my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that unless there is a strong business requirement for custom Ids, you not implement them. I think there is just one up vote for the post you mention because not too many people are implementing custom id generation as it doesn't pass the smell test, in my opinion.